# Does MySQL included with MAMP not include a config file?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc, my.cnf

I can't seem to find the my.cnf or other config file for the MySQL that comes with MAMP. Does it not include one?

I want to use NetBeans for Java/MySQL Development and many articles on the web suggest that I comment out a line in my.cnf

---

Resolved this by editing the MySQL startup parameters file and commenting out
"skip-networking".

```
skip-networking
```

in /etc/my.cnf

changed to:

```
#skip-networking
```

I understand that MAMP doesn't have a my.cnf so how can I get NetBeans to work with MySQL?

Comment: Should be of some help: http://blog.evandavey.com/2009/11/how-to-create-my-cnf-file-in-mamp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.evandavey.com/2009/11/how-to-create-my-cnf-file-in-mamp.html

Answer (score 0):

MAMP uses it's own my.cnf which should be editted ***IN* MAMP**.

1. Open MAMP application
2. Go to File => Edit Template => MySQL my.cnf
3. Make your desired changes
4. Restart server
5. Check e.g. by running query SHOW VARIABLES